# iOS Swift - Video picker from library/gallery

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, video

I'm trying to implement a feature to pick videos from the gallery from an iPhone.

Here is my function :

```
func openVideoGallery()
    {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self as UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
        picker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .savedPhotosAlbum)!
        picker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]

        picker.allowsEditing = false
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Here is my questions :

- I was wondering is it the right way to pick up videos from the gallery using `UIImagePickerController` ?
- How can I get the path to video selected ?

Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

1- Yes

2-  implemet

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let asset =  info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset {

        asset.getURL { (tempPath) in 

        }

    }
    else  if let media =  info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {

    }
    else
        if let ref =  info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.referenceURL] as? URL {

    }
}
```

---

Change this

```
picker.delegate = self as UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

to

```
picker.delegate = self
```

and make the vc conform to

```
class VCName: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the asset being a PHAsset has no member 'getURL' ! What can I do about it please ?